# How can I run 2 asynchrones code in one function and escape them?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, swift4.2

I want to run 2 pieces of asynchronous code in one function and escape them. I want first to download the Reciter information and then download with these information the images that is associated with the Reciter. I'm using Firestore. I tried to work with DispatchQueue and DispatchGroup but I couldn't figure something out. I hope someone can help me :)

```
func getReciters(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        var reciters = [Reciter]()
            self.BASE_URL.collection(REF_RECITERS).getDocuments { (snapchot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    debugPrint(error)
                    completion(false)
                    // TODO ADD UIALTERCONTROLLER MESSAGE
                    return
                }

                guard let snapchot = snapchot else { debugPrint("NO SNAPSHOT"); completion(false); return }

                for reciter in snapchot.documents {
                    let data = reciter.data()
                    let reciterName = data[REF_RECITER_NAME] as? String ?? "ERROR"
                    let numberOfSurahs = data[REF_NUMBER_OF_SURAHS] as? Int ?? 0

// **HERE I WANT TO DOWNLOAD THE IMAGES**
                    self.downloadImage(forDocumentID: reciter.documentID, completion: { (image) in
                        let reciter = Reciter(name: reciterName, image: nil, surahCount: numberOfSurahs, documentID: reciter.documentID)
                        reciters.append(reciter)
                    })
                }
            }
        UserDefaults.standard.saveReciters(reciters)
        completion(true)
    }
```

Comment: Just put `completion(true)` inside the `downloadImage` block?

Comment: you need yo implement it with dispatch group ... read multi threading in depth.

Comment: Tj3n: Then it's called on every loop which I don't want

Comment: Abu UI Hassan: can you give me a quick simple example how to use these the right way because I tried dispatch group before. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `DispatchGroup`.

- In the scope of the function declare an instance of `DispatchGroup`.
- In the loop **before** the asynchronous block call `enter`.
- In the loop **inside** the completion handler of the asynchronous block call `leave`.
- After the loop call `notify`, the closure will be executed after all asynchronous tasks have finished.

---

```
func getReciters(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    var reciters = [Reciter]()
    self.BASE_URL.collection(REF_RECITERS).getDocuments { (snapchot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
            completion(false)
            // TODO ADD UIALTERCONTROLLER MESSAGE
            return
        }

        guard let snapchot = snapchot else { debugPrint("NO SNAPSHOT"); completion(false); return }
        let group = DispatchGroup()

        for reciter in snapchot.documents {
            let data = reciter.data()
            let reciterName = data[REF_RECITER_NAME] as? String ?? "ERROR"
            let numberOfSurahs = data[REF_NUMBER_OF_SURAHS] as? Int ?? 0
            group.enter()

            self.downloadImage(forDocumentID: reciter.documentID, completion: { (image) in
                let reciter = Reciter(name: reciterName, image: nil, surahCount: numberOfSurahs, documentID: reciter.documentID)
                reciters.append(reciter)
                group.leave()
            })
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            UserDefaults.standard.saveReciters(reciters)
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :) But i have a question: Doesn't it leave the dispatch group on every loop when it executes the downloadImage() function? If yes why it works then?

Comment: *Think asynchronous*. `downloadImage` works asynchronously, the completion handler is called much later in time. Imagine `DispatchGroup` as a counter, `enter` increases the counter (quickly), `leave` decreases it (slower). When the counter reaches zero, the closure in `notify` is called.

Comment: Aaaah makes sense. Thank you